# view incorrectly reloads after uniqueness validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

After you try to submit a new guideline and you see an error message on the form (due to the guidelines correctly failing validation)...the list of @specialties does not reload correctly (ie. it just says yes/no rather than the proper list you could see before you submitted with an error).  I can't work out which part is wrong here...

**VIEWS _form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@guideline, html: {class: "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
  <% if @guideline.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@guideline.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this guideline from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @guideline.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>


  <%= f.input :title, label: 'Title (e.g. Asthma for under 12 months)' %>
  <%= f.input :specialty, as: :select, collection: @specialties %> 
  <%= f.input :hospital %>
  <%= f.input :content, as: :string, label: 'Link' %>


  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => "btn btn-info btn-large" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**guidelines_controller.rb**

```
 def new
    @guideline = Guideline.new
    @specialties = Guideline.order(:specialty).uniq.pluck(:specialty)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @guideline }

    end
  end



def create
@guideline = current_user.guidelines.new(params[:guideline])



respond_to do |format|
  if @guideline.save
    format.html { redirect_to @guideline, notice: 'Guideline was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render json: @guideline, status: :created, location: @guideline }
  else

    @specialties = Guideline.order(:specialty).uniq.pluck(:specialty)
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @guideline.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a common error. in your create action you should declare @specialties if the validation fails since that is needed in the new template.

```
def create
  @guideline = Guideline.new params[:guideline]

  if @guideline.save
  else
    # you need to declare @specialties here since it is needed in the new template
    # which you want to render
    @specialties = Specialty.all
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks!  very pleased I am making common errors - this is strangely reassuring.  Have printed my correct create action above in case anyone might find it useful.